# Custom vs Generic Views in Django

Tags: python, django, view, django-views

The question is about generic views, and their use in practice. They are presented  as a better, cleaner, alternative for writing custom views, however they didn't seem to simply the view code much, and seemed very case specific. So in practice, are these generic views used extensively, with custom ones written only for very specific cases? Or is it the opposite, and generic views only exist for minimalists/case specific needs?

Comment: The generic views are used extensively, they cover most common use cases. In what way do they not simplify your views?

Comment: The thing is, they look that way but they do everything u want. They have all the methods you can think of in custom views as you call them. Give them a try, you'll be surprised....

Comment: Ok so in practice, there are enough generic views to cover almost every use case, and therefore custom ones are rarely used?

Answer (score 1):

The most common operations for any backend application, are create, read, update and delete - more commonly known as CRUD operations. These will cover almost all use-cases for your API. Generic views provide methods for these operations and much more, meaning that you don't have to repeat the same code over and over again throughout your application. These classes and methods provided by the DRF are also extensible, allowing you to alter them to your needs, when required.

Comment: I know what they are/what they are used for, my question is more about their use in practice